# Xxode - Program crashes, no output to log

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Here's the code snippet that causes the crash:

```
NSLog(@"Exercises:");
 for (Exercise *exercise in self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects) 
  NSLog(@"%@ : %@", exercise.name);
```

When corrected it does not crash:

```
NSLog(@"Exercises:");
 for (Exercise *exercise in self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects) 
  NSLog(@"%@", exercise.name);
```

I'm curious, as to why doesn't XCode report an error to the Log Console when my app crashes?

Comment: Are you running in Debug mode (Command-Y)?

Comment: Thanks Zeppomedio, when I run in Debug mode (Command-Y) I get:

2010-12-12 14:46:50.598 BB_CD_v2[387:207] Exercises: Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. So it all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS it generally means you tried to access something from memory that isn't there.

In your case, it's expecting a 2nd parameter here:

```
NSLog(@"%@ : %@", exercise.name);
```

I see that you already corrected it though. Nice work. As mentioned above, Command-Y gives you access to the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Digging around in the doco you can also specify the index of the value for each specifier. So

```
NSLog(@"%1$@ : %1$@", exercise.name);
```

Should work because the `$1` specifies which value to use. Check out [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) for details.